# Calculate values of multiple input fields that are added by javascript codee and display for every row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate result for each row, I used javascript that add multiple rows, and I want calculation on every row.

```js
function sub() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('AB[]').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('RAB').value;
  var resultMul = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
  var textthired = document.getElementById('RQP').value;
  var result = parseInt(textthired) + parseInt(resultMul);

  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('TA[]').value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="AB[]" onkeyup="sub();" id="AB[]" min="5" max="1000" required>

<input type="text" name="TA[]" id="TA[]" readonly>
<input type="text" name="RQP" value="1500" readonly onkeyup="sub();" id="RQP">
<input type="text" name="RAB" value="50" readonly onkeyup="sub();" id="RAB">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all last two fields are readonly so keyup function will not work.
2. Second you add value only when there is any entry in the field by checking entered value as greater than 0

Comment: it can perform calculation on first input as first input also entered by user and other 2 values are read only...but it can't perform calculation on other fields. please give me some suggestions about this.